# Zurb Foundation: site no longer mobile responsive

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design, sass, zurb-foundation

Code is here: https://github.com/michaelrbock/personal-site/blob/master/index.html

For some reason this site is no longer mobile-responsive (specifically on iPhone) when previously it was, and I'm not sure why this is. When opening the page on an iPhone (for example), the page should look different, specifically the menu bar should have a drop-down and the width of the page should fit the screen exactly.

I have included this line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and haven't really changed much, so I'm not sure why it's no longer responsive.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Responsive" is a pretty vague term, so you'd get better answers if you explained specifically what is not happening, and what you're expecting so see.  You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: Good points, thank you. I've updated the question to reflect some of your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded your site's files from GitHub to my local machine and tested them, they appear to be working perfectly fine with no errors anywhere. The site is responsive and acting like it should. The menu you had mentioned appears to be working fine and shrinks from text to a dropdown when you hit iphone size. I opened it on my iphone and again no errors.

If you have any other issues which are not being mentioned please put them in the comments, it appears you've either fixed the issue you were having or it has fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need this line in the `<head>` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```